# Proof about orders of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Assume $f:G \rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism between groups $G$ and $H$ and that a is an element of $G$ then order(f(a))=order(a)

Approach:
let $l$ be the order of $a$ and $t$ be the order of $f(a)$, so $l$ and $t$ are smallest positive integers such that $a^l=1_G$ and $f(a)^t=1_H$. We have to show $l=t$

One crucial point is to note that if $a=1_G$ then $f(1_G)=1_H$. I proved this already, so we can say since f is homomorphic
$$1_H=f(a^l=1_G)=f(a*a^{l-1})=f(a)*f(a^{l-1})=f(a)*f(a*a^{l-2})=...=f(a)^l$$

I just used the fact that $f$ is homomorphic, but why is $f$ being bijective relevant?. Besides that, I am not sure if the proof is complete. It looks very incomplete to me. What if $l$ is a multiple of $t$?

Comment: You have shown that $f(a)^l = 1_H$, which means that the order of $f(a)$ is a divisor of $l$. This does not imply that $f(a)$ equals $l$. You will need bijectivity to prove that.

Comment: Also, unless there is an implicit assumption that the the groups are finite, note that $a$ and $f(a)$ could have infinite order.

Comment: By what you showed, the order of $f(a)$ is less than or equal to the order of $a$, $t\le l$. But the inverse of the isomorphism $f$ is an isomorphism from $H$ to $G$, so $l\le t$. Thus $l=t$.

Comment: How do we show  $order(f(a))$ is a divisor of $l$?. By definition we can map the identity with multiples of the order, but how do we know that these are the only ones that map the identity?

Comment: @Bungo ?????????

Comment: @AndréNicolas    ????

Comment: @TheMathNoob By the division algorithm, we can write $l = qt + r$ where $q$ and $r$ are integers, and $0 \leq r < t$. Therefore $1 = f(a)^l = f(a)^{qt + r} = (f(a)^t)^q f(a)^r = f(a)^r$ since $f(a)^t = 1$. As $t$ is the smallest positive integer such that $f(a) = 1$, this forces $r = 0$, so $l = qt$, which means that $t$ divides $l$, as claimed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written seems good for a beginner. Here is a more refined proof.

Let $l$ be the order of $a$ in $G$.

Note that $(f(a))^l$ = $f(a) * f(a) * ... * f(a) = f(a * a * ... * a) = f(a^l)$.

Hence it follows that if $a^l = 1_G$ then $f(a^l) = f(1_G) = 1_H$.

Now, suppose there exists $m$ smaller than $l$ such  that $(f(a))^m = 1_H$. Then:

$1_H=(f(a))^m$ = $f(a) * f(a) * ... * f(a) = f(a * a * ... * a) = f(a^m)$.

Hence $f(a^m) = 1_H$ and $a^m$ is in the kernel of $f$. However, because $f$ is an isomorphism, the only element in the kernel of $f$ is $1_G$, hence $a^m=1_G$, which contradicts the fact that $l>m$ was the order of $a$ in $G$.

Hence $m$ cannot be the order of $f(a)$ for and $m<l$, and hence $\text{ord}(f(a)) = l = \text{ord}(a)$

Comment: However, because $f$ is an isomorphism, the only element in the kernel of $f$ is $1_G$ why is that true? why does just the identity map the identity?

Comment: That is a standard result. Let me prove it. Suppose the kernel contains another element $k$. Then, let $h$ be an element of $H$. Now, because our map is a bijection, it follows that there exists some $g$ in $G$ such that $f(g)= h$ by surjectivity. However, $f(a * g) = f(a) * f(g) = 1_G * f(g) = f(g) = h$, therefore $f(ag) =f(g) = h$. This contradicts injectivity of the isomorphism, hence the kernel cannot contain any other element.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, we know for sure that the identity maps the identity, so if there is another element that maps the identity then f is not injective anymore

Comment: Perfect. That was even easier.